# Disassembly of a bytecode *file*?

Tags: byte-compilation, bytecode

There is a disassembler for functions, but is there something that will disassemble a bytecode file?

Thoughts on how to accomplish?

Comment: I'd figure out how exactly the .elc format works. It appears to be designed so that you can just `read` the file, if that's indeed the case you could hopefully do a tree mapping operation and disassemble every bytecode object you come across.

Answer (score 5):

With [`cl-print.el`](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-print.html) (builtin as of Emacs 26), this is actually pretty easy to do almost perfectly:

```el
(require 'cl-print)

(defun disassemble-file (filename)
  (let ((inbuf (find-file-noselect filename)))
    (with-current-buffer inbuf
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*file disassembly*")
      (erase-buffer)
      (condition-case ()
          (cl-loop with cl-print-compiled = 'disassemble
                   for expr = (read inbuf)
                   do (pcase expr
                        (`(byte-code ,(pred stringp) ,(pred vectorp) ,(pred natnump))
                         (princ "TOP-LEVEL byte code:\n" (current-buffer))
                         (disassemble-1 expr 0))
                        (_ (cl-prin1 expr (current-buffer))))
                   do (terpri (current-buffer)))          
        (end-of-file nil))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (display-buffer (current-buffer)))))
```

The only thing this misses is disassembling the bytecode of closures which will be constructed by disassembled code, e.g.:

```
7       constant  make-byte-code
8       constant  0
9       constant  "\301\300!\205    \0\302\300!\207"
10      constant  vconcat
11      constant  vector
12      stack-ref 5
13      call      1
14      constant  [buffer-name kill-buffer]
```

Perhaps `disassemble` could be improved to handle this case better.

Answer (score 2):

Files with byte-code contain `read`able functions just like `.el` files, with the biggest difference being how docstrings are stored, it's explained [here in the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Docs-and-Compilation.html#Docs-and-Compilation). If you want to dump out disassembly for every byte-code object, you'd have to write code that walks across the expressions in the `.elc` file and writes them somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I got that from wasamasa's useful comment. I was (and still am) looking for something a little more detailed, such as code like https://github.com/rocky/elisp-decompile/blob/master/elisp/dedis.el#L45-L58   which does the trivial part, but there still is walking the expressions. It also looks like there are some constants have a value of  <compiled-function> which need more information filled out.

Comment: `read` can take a marker as an argument and advance it, that should make things easier.